# Installation of Expect on Windows 7 64-bit fails with "not found in the archives"

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, expect

1. Downloaded ActiveTcl from http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/
2. Installed ActiveTcl at `c:/Tcl/`
3. Go to Bin directory in command prompt (Start > Run > `cmd` > `cd c:\Tcl\bin`)
4. To install Expect, I executed the command `teacup install Expect`

I got the following message:

```
Resolving Expect ... Not found in the archives.

While a more fuzzy search disregarding letter case and accepting
substrings was done, we are sorry to say that it yielded no possible
candidates for installation either.

Questions to consider:
        Have you spelled the name correctly ?
        Including the proper case of characters ?

Note that teacup's 'search' command allows you to locate packages by
subject, categories, and the like.


Aborting installation, was not able to locate the requested
entity.
```

How do I install Expect on Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

Expect has not 64bit version, you can only download and install 32bit active tcl and then do teacup install Expect.
anyway, Expect has some defects running on 64bit windows...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [32-bit Windows Installer](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/thank-you?dl=http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.6.1.0/ActiveTcl8.6.1.0.297577-win32-ix86-threaded.exe) instead of the 64-bit Windows Installer for ActiveTcl.

Pansion suggested that the Expect package is 32-bit and won't work with 64-bit Tcl -- I had the same problem and after downloading the 32-bit version, `teacup search Expect` showed a `win32-ix86` Expect package. Then `teacup install Expect` installed the package correctly.

You can also try installing an older version of Tcl - 4.6.20.0 [32-bit](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/thank-you?dl=http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.4.20.0/ActiveTcl8.4.20.0.297203-win32-ix86-threaded.exe) has Expect included in the Tcl install.